# How to use a KineticJS | Canvas element as a HTML background.

Tags: animation, canvas, background, cordova, kineticjs

I need to make a background animation for a Phonegap project. How can I make this happen? I do have some beginner Kineticjs skills but I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: #canvas {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:-1;
        position:fixed; 
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .content {
        z-index:1;
        overflow:scroll;
        height:100%;
    }

With two css I able to do that. Thanks :D

Comment: So did you solve your own question? If so I would recommend answering your own question and marking it as the accepted answer..

Comment: İshould wait like 10 hours for able to do that :) And 24 hours for mark it too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#canvas {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.content {
    z-index:1;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100%;
}
```

With two css I able to do that. Thanks :D